# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and trying to run Python 3.4 - 64-bit but the interactive window shows `<disconnected>`. If I try to restart it - I get the following error:

```
Method Not found:'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.SpanMicrosoft.VisualStudio.InteractiveWindow.IInteractiveWindow.WriteErro(System.String)'.
```

I've tried to reinstall the updated and appropriate python tool kit. I've even repaired my installation of visual studio. The interactive window is nonfunctional and I can't type anything into the window. This is true if I change the interpreter to 2.7. Configure interactive window properties doesn't have any options that will connect it to the python interpreter.

Python Debug Interactive also doesn't work and gives the same error.
Right click > Highlighting code > send to interactive, in a `.py` file that is open (which runs fine) also gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you need to install a separate interpreter (CPython, IronPython), as described here: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation

Comment: I reinstalled both and used Anaconda which worked. Thanks.